# Reducing the size of a LVM on LUKS generated warnings

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm, luks

Hi I have been following this helpful guide (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Resizing_LVM-on-LUKS) on how to reduce the size of my filesystem and partitions to generate roughly 100G of free space on the partition table to install Windows along sign my Ubuntu installation.

I have noticed several warnings appearing when using LVM commands after doing `pvresize` and also alarming some commands are reporting in PiB instead of GiB, which makes me thinks I may have miscalculated something. I have stopped what I am doing the reduce the risk of needing to wipe the machine and start again. The essential data is backed up, but I would still prefer not to do a rebuild.

The error messages are

```bash
  WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/cryptdisk has size of 762478592 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 799508162148352 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG vgubuntu have changed sizes.
```

Below is the output of the various diagnostic commands I know to check wether

```bash
> sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WD_BLACK SN770 500GB                    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 71C114FE-3DBF-4E71-A422-6CE906592E52

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624   4550655   3500032   1.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 4550656 976771071 972220416 463.6G Linux filesystem
```

```bash
> sudo lvdisplay

  WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/cryptdisk has size of 762478592 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 799508162148352 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG vgubuntu have changed sizes.
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgubuntu/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                vgubuntu
  LV UUID                hPTH7U-FRG1-VPcT-OgAk-S2lY-pD5O-hR8ixl
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2023-07-23 19:58:39 +0000
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                361.66 GiB
  Current LE             92586
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgubuntu/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                vgubuntu
  LV UUID                B5vW6H-cMcc-i0rt-CuEM-EC6a-tVQb-474jVv
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2023-07-23 19:58:39 +0000
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                1.91 GiB
  Current LE             489
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     autosh
```

```bash
> sudo vgdisplay

  WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/cryptdisk has size of 762478592 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 799508162148352 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG vgubuntu have changed sizes.
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vgubuntu
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               11.57 PiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              3106930687
  Alloc PE / Size       93075 / 363.57 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       3106837612 / 11.57 PiB
  VG UUID               oIyZSZ-Ibd3-8Tjm-RpSf-wVts-ru19-88uWCR
```

```bash
> sudo pvdisplay 

  WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/cryptdisk has size of 762478592 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 799508162148352 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG vgubuntu have changed sizes.
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/cryptdisk
  VG Name               vgubuntu
  PV Size               363.57 PiB / not usable 352.00 PiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              3106930687
  Free PE               3106837612
  Allocated PE          93075
  PV UUID               XVxLuX-GtmB-CvcP-whyf-C1gN-n6yx-CXLzSA
```

```bash
> sudo pvs -v --segments /dev/mapper/cryptdisk
  
WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/cryptdisk has size of 762478592 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 799508162148352 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG vgubuntu have changed sizes.
  PV                    VG       Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree  Start  SSize      LV     Start Type   PE Ranges                          
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk vgubuntu lvm2 a--  11.57p 11.57p      0      92586 root       0 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:0-92585      
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk vgubuntu lvm2 a--  11.57p 11.57p  92586      25600            0 free                                      
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk vgubuntu lvm2 a--  11.57p 11.57p 118186        489 swap_1     0 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:118186-118674
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk vgubuntu lvm2 a--  11.57p 11.57p 118675 3106812012
```

My challenge with some of these commands is I am not certain of what units some stats are given in and what looks like a correct value and what looks like an incorrect value. However `PV Size               363.57 PiB / not usable 352.00 PiB` looks wrong to me when I am expecting a things to about around 360GB.

Any help reading these command outputs and letting me know if I have a genuinely problem before I continue resizing LUKS and then the partition, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I know what I did now. When running `pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize ######B /dev/mapper/cryptdisk` I did not notice the B in the guide so I just wrote the desired number of bytes. I then think the tool defaulted to megabytes, which resized the PV to be a factor of 1024^2 (or 10^6, I forget which) too big. It seems like I cannot just run `pvresize` with the corrected value, probably meaning I need to use `pvmove`.